# Unable to setup native base in my react-native app

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to setup native-base in react native app. I have followed all the steps and trying to run App on ios simulator. But I'm getting the error like below.

**Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SAW.app/Info.plist**
**Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist.**

what I'm doing wrong?
I'm using below versions.

**Does native base support react native version 0.56.0 or not?**

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

```
{
"name": "SAW",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
"native-base": "^2.7.2",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "23.4.2",
"babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
"jest": "23.5.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your `info.plist` file (found in the iOS folder)

Answer (score 0):

`CFBundleIdentifier` has got nothing to do with NativeBase.

Also you can check NativeBase vs React Native version compatibility here https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#7-compatibility-versions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your port 8081 is in use. Check for `lsof -n -i4TCP:8081` and kill any processes using 8081 and try running again.

If nothing works, try running on the Xcode.

For further readings, check out [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308)